# Find replace number followed by character in quotes inside parenthesis visual studio 2019

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to change all string arguments to function DEBUG(mode) to enum and all strings starting with an integer will have m added to the front:

Examples:

| Original | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `DEBUG("LOG_EVENTS")` | `DEBUG(LOG_EVENTS)` |
| `DEBUG("3b")` | `DEBUG(m3b)` |

I have:

```
Find: DEBUG\\("([a-zA-Z]+\.h)"\\)
Replace: DEBUG\\($1\\)
```

and

```
Find: DEBUG\\("([0-9]+h)"\\)
Replace: DEBUG\\(m$1\\)
```

but I find 0 occurrences for both queries.

Comment: `(` indicates the start of a capture group. If you need a literal `(` then prepend with backslash `\(`. Also pay attention to other regex chars which have special meaning.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I had the backslashes there but they were removed by stack overflow, added double \\ and fixed it. This is how my original queries actually look now.

Comment: What is `h` in your finds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for the leading alpha search:

```
Find: DEBUG\("([a-zA-Z]\w*)"\)
Replace: DEBUG($1)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ct4YcIWKzyv5Y1).

and this for the leading numeric search:

```
Find: DEBUG\("(\d\w+)"\)
Replace: DEBUG(m$1)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/teRCPtKo5Ge9ni).

---

I think your basic problem is the "h" in your find terms.

Comment: thank you. Can you make it so the alpha search includes numbers? I just ran the second one first so leading numeric replacements are fixed.

Comment: @MatthewCole done. You can use them in either order.